# Как проапдейтить записи в базе с помощью Формы Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

У меня есть такая модель:
**models.py**

```
class GroupModel(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True,blank=True)
   year_id = models.ForeignKey(YearModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   course_id = models.ForeignKey(CourseModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   special_id = models.ForeignKey(SpecialModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   educational_part_id = models.ForeignKey(EducationalPartModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   start_date_autumn = models.DateField(verbose_name='Начало весеннеого семестра')
   end_date_autumn = models.DateField(verbose_name='Конец весеннеого семестра')
   start_date_spring = models.DateField(verbose_name='Начало осеннего семестра')
   end_date_spring = models.DateField(verbose_name='Конец осеннего семестра')

   def __str__(self):
       return self.name

   class Meta:
       verbose_name = 'Группа'
       verbose_name_plural = 'Группы'
```

Из этой модели, я отображаю следующие поля в шаблоне Django, для каждой записи:
Специальность, Курс, Наименование группы.

Мне необходимо, чтобы пользователь мог отредактировать данные по группе в шаблоне Django, пытался сделать следующим образом:
Создал форму в шаблоне Django:

```
<form id="myform" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <table id="maintable">
            <col style="width:99%"> 
            <tr>
                
                <td>Cпециальность</td>
                <td>
                    <select class="sub-menu-subjects" name="select_special" id="">
                        {% for special in specials %}
                            <option selected hidden>{{ group.special_id.name }}</option>
                            <option value="{{ special.name }}">{{ special.name }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </td>
                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Группа</td>
                <td>
                    <select class="sub-menu-subjects" name="select_group" id="">
                        {% for group in groups %}
                            <option selected hidden>{{ group }}</option>
                            <option value="{{ group.name }}">{{ group.name }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Курс</td>
                <td>
                    <select class="sub-menu-subjects" name="select_course" id="" >
                        {% for course in courses %}
                            <option selected hidden>{{ group.course_id.id }}</option>
                            <option value="{{ course.name }}" >{{ course.name }}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Данная форма отправляется во вью, с помощью кнопки:

```
<input form="myform" type="submit" value="Сохранить">
```

Из этой формы, получилось достать выбранные значения пользователем с помощью метода = POST во вью:

```
def redactor_about_group(request,group_id):

if request.method == 'POST':
    select_special = request.POST.get('select_special')
    select_group = request.POST.get('select_group')
    select_course = request.POST.get('select_course')
    print(select_special,select_group,select_course)

group = get_object_or_404(GroupModel, pk = group_id)
groups = GroupModel.objects.all()
courses = CourseModel.objects.all()
specials = SpecialModel.objects.all()
context = {"groups" : groups, "group" : group, "courses" : courses, "specials" : specials}
return render(request, "main/deportament/redactor/redactor_about_group.html",context)
```

Дальше хотелось бы понять, как я могу данные значения проапдейтить в базе данных.

UPD:
Группу удалось проапдейтить, дописав пару строчек во вью:

```
group.name = select_group
group.save()
```

При попытке поступить аналогичным образом со специальностью и курсом, получаю ошибку:

```
Cannot assign "5": "GroupModel.course_id" must be a "CourseModel" instance.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка Вам все сказала, собственно)

`Cannot assign "5": "GroupModel.course_id" must be a "CourseModel" instance.`

В поле `course_id` надо подставить не число введенное пользователем, а ссылку на `CourseModel` ( а Вы еще и не число пытаетесь вставить, а строку `value="{{ course.name }}"` имени из формы, да и если бы число передавали - все данные из формы, на сколько помню, достаются в виде строки).

В модели Вы указали что эти поля являются внешним ключем.

```
year_id = models.ForeignKey(YearModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
course_id = models.ForeignKey(CourseModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
special_id = models.ForeignKey(SpecialModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
educational_part_id = models.ForeignKey(EducationalPartModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Что бы избежать ошибки, необходимо:

1. Сохранять в форме идентификатор модели, а не его имя. `value="{{ course.id }}"`. Этот шаг не обязателен, во вьюхе можно искать и по имени, но а - оно может быть не уникальным, б- по нему скорее всего не будет индекса(как в Вашем случае), а поиск по первичному ключу будет куда быстрее.`id` или другое поле, Вы не выложили информации о других моделях.
2. Найти этот курс/специальность/тд и сохранить его в поле.

```
select_course = request.POST.get('select_course')
cource = CourseModel.objects.get(id=int(select_course))  # повторюсь, что id - это пример, Вам надо использовать ваш PrimaryKey
group.name = select_group
group.cpurce_id = cource  # связь задается таким образом
group.save()
```

Comment: Понял, спасибо за такой подробный ответ, получилось разобраться.

Comment: Хотел еще уточнить пару вопросов по разрабатываемому сайту, можем перейти в TG? Или в чат обсуждений StackOverflow, если у вас конечно есть время.

Comment: @roxyashechka Не знаю как тут чат создать, если дадите ссылку - зайду)

Comment: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126140/django-python